# Crawler Search problem

Tags: uninstall

I am using ubuntu 10.04 and firefox for my web browsing.  All the sudden crawler became my search provider so I went in to the search bar to the right top and deleted the crawler from the list and also deleted all add-ons that remotely looked like it was related.  Now whenever I use the address bar for searches it is still using crawler.  How do I get rid of this deceptive little product.

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 0):

try `rm -r $HOME/.crawler`

else, find `./mozilla/[your profile]/addons.sqlite` and (if you know how to) delete database entry for it.

with top/htop, ps and grep in terminal you can more/less determine how crawler starts, if you go and look by pid number.

These are hacks, mind you.

also, creating a brand new profile, import previously exported setting and bookmarks to it should greatly help your case. And is probably much easier. Mind you, you must start firefox from terminal with `firefox -no-remote --ProfileManager`

`sudo apt-get --autoremove remove firefox --purge`
`sudo apt-get install firefox` could help too

Answer (score 0):

From [Mozilla's support page](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-web-address-bar):

To set Google as the default search engine when you type in your address bar, first type:

```
about:config
```

in the address bar of `firefox`.
It will show a message to be careful, click on `I promise I'll be careful.`

In the search bar that now appears, type `keyword.url`. Double click on the `value` field and paste this:  `https://www.google.com/search?q=`. Click `OK` and close this tab. Open a new tab and start searching through the address bar!

Refer the link given above in this post to set it to some other search engine.